# Problemas para desplegar el Formulario en el Template usando CreateView

Tags: python, django

Lo que pasa es que estoy usando **CreateView** y me parece curioso que funcione el codigo cuando pongo **{{ form }}**, me despliega todos los campos y guarda en la base de datos(todo funciona muy bien) pero cuando desgloso los valores uno por uno por ejemplo: **{{ form.placas }}, {{ form.tipo }}**, no manda nada a la base de datos y se queda en la misma página ¿Eso a qué se debe? Yo justamente lo necesito desglosado

> clientes-add.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <div class="row mb-3">
             <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="mb-3">
                     <label>Customer type</label>
                <br>
                 <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      {{ form.tipo }}
                   </div>

                 </div>
              </div>
            </div>
           <div class="row mb-3 only-corp hide-item">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                          <label>Corporation name</label>
                              {{ form.corporacion }}
                     </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
<button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="submit" value="Post">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Prueba a poner en vez de `{{ form.corporacion }}` un `<input type="text" name="corporation" id="id_corporation"/>`. Con el `name` igual al nombre del campo y el `id` igual a id_ + nombre del campo.

Comment: sí aparecen los campos pero no manda los datos del formulario, parece que mi problema es más un asunto de HTML

Answer (score 1):

CreateView es un tipo de vista genérica que muestra de forma predeterminada los parámetros del formulario. Si quieres algo más personalizado, en tu **forms.py** tendrías que hacer tu propio formulario personalizado: [Documentación para generar formularios personalizados](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)

Comment: muchas gracias, lo reviso :D